# Tensorflow Load model in C++ API and get "from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY" error

Tags: c++, tensorflow

My model is about 2.4GB。In my inference step, I want to load model by multi-processing method in each GPU. That means I try to make two process in one GPU and each load a model。
After I make configuration of each session done, each session get about 5GB memory, But I still meet the "from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY"。I am wondering。。。 Asking for help

**GPU information:**

[search@qrwt01 /home/s/apps/qtfserverd/bin]$ nvidia-smi
Thu Sep 14 21:42:48 2017

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 375.26 Driver Version: 375.26 |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU Name Persistence-M| Bus-Id Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan Temp Perf Pwr:Usage/Cap| Memory-Usage | GPU-Util Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
| 0 Tesla K80 Off | 0000:08:00.0 Off | 0 |
| N/A 48C P0 61W / 149W | 11366MiB / 11439MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| 1 Tesla K80 Off | 0000:09:00.0 Off | 0 |
| N/A 32C P0 72W / 149W | 11359MiB / 11439MiB | 0% Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes: GPU Memory |
| GPU PID Type Process name Usage |
|=============================================================================|
| 0 33056 C ...ome/s/apps/qtfserverd/etc/qtfserverd.conf 5823MiB |
| 0 33057 C ...ome/s/apps/qtfserverd/etc/qtfserverd.conf 5515MiB |
| 1 33058 C ...ome/s/apps/qtfserverd/etc/qtfserverd.conf 5823MiB |
| 1 33059 C ...ome/s/apps/qtfserverd/etc/qtfserverd.conf 5516MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

**Session configuration:**

```
void* create_session(void* graph, std::string& checkpoint_path,
    int intra_op_threads, int inter_op_threads, std::string& device_list) {
Session* session = NULL;
SessionOptions sess_opts;
//int NUM_THREADS = 8;
if (intra_op_threads > 0) {
    sess_opts.config.set_intra_op_parallelism_threads(intra_op_threads);
}
if (inter_op_threads > 0) {
    sess_opts.config.set_inter_op_parallelism_threads(inter_op_threads);
}

sess_opts.config.set_allow_soft_placement(true);
sess_opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_visible_device_list(device_list);
sess_opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allocator_type("BFC");
sess_opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_per_process_gpu_memory_fraction(0.5);
sess_opts.config.mutable_gpu_options()->set_allow_growth(true);
Status status = NewSession(sess_opts, &session);
if (!status.ok()) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Create Session Failed %s\n", status.ToString().c_str());
    return NULL;
 }
```

**Error information**

load /home/search/tensorflow/deploy_combine.model.meta graph to /gpu:1 success
2017-09-14 21:42:31.188212: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:965] Found device 0 with properties:
name: Tesla K80 major: 3 minor: 7 memoryClockRate(GHz): 0.8235
pciBusID: 0000:09:00.0
totalMemory: 11.17GiB freeMemory: 11.05GiB
2017-09-14 21:42:31.188260: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1055] Creating TensorFlow device (/device:GPU:0) -> (device: 1, name: Tesla K80, pci bus id: 0000:09:00.0, compute capability: 3.7)
qss_switch:1, lstm_switch:1
qss_switch:1, lstm_switch:1
2017-09-14 21:42:33.826598: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 1.58G (1701773312 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.838694: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 1.43G (1531596032 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.893832: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 439.82M (461180672 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.903917: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 439.82M (461180672 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.913843: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 439.82M (461180672 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.924008: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 439.82M (461180672 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.935385: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 439.82M (461180672 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.946556: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:936] failed to allocate 439.82M (461180672 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
2017-09-14 21:42:33.956340: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.

Answer (score 0):

Try reducing the parameters of your operation or do the computation in batches because the error is indicating that all the GPU resources have been exhausted.